# Computing number of lines with given width and font size

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

Let me tell you my requirement first,

I have `strings` stored in one string variable say str,

```
NSString *str=@"multiple strings";
```

Next I would like to specify the width where the above strings will get fit into,say width=350 and fontsize=16; Now how would I get to know how many lines the texts will get occupy with given width=350 and fontsize=15.(I mean number of lines)

Comment: do you mean if it is word-wrapped, breaking on whitespace?

Comment: @danh..no,just want to know the number of lines.my intention is to find the height dynamically with given width and fontsize...

Comment: NSString provides a method sizeWithFont: where you can pass a font (like [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]), but that will tell you the height of a single line.  Number of lines is an unclear requirement unless we know what constitutes a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the size (and hence the height) required to draw a string by using one of the methods in `UIStringDrawing.h`. This method will give you the size when drawing into a constrained width of 350px:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(350, CGFLOAT_MAX);
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

In this example, `maximumSize` uses the maximum possible height (effectively infinity) for a `CGFloat`, and a width of 350px. This effectively means "*give me the size of this text by restricting the width to 350px*".

Comment: what is this 350 stands for?...and what it will do...i think its a constrained width,but what is the use of constrained width?..pls clear my doubt...

Comment: @PKCoder answer edited to explain the `constrainedToSize:` argument explicitly.

Comment: This answer isn't complete. `size` gives the required height of the string in points. You still need to divide that by the line height to get the number of lines as asked for in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy The OP followed up in a comment with 'my intention is to find the height dynamically with given width and fontsize'. I took that to mean that the end goal was finding the height, not the number of lines.

Comment: @NickForge The title, the question, and PKCoder's comment to the question all mention wanting the number of lines. Then again, the question comment does mention a height. I missed that. So perhaps your question is complete after all. Sorry.